# How to make a condition on php in Opencart 2?

Tags: php

Im trying to make a condition in Opencart 2.

If the goods in the catalog are less than 18, then print the text, otherwise do not output the text.

When I use this code, nothing changes.

```
<?php
    if ($products < 18) {
        echo ('Some text');
    }
    else {
        echo ('Some other text')
    } 
?>
```

Maybe I need to create some variables? How to do this correctly?

Comment: This code does not say much about your problem. You need to provide more details.

Comment: Why did you put `echo` after `else` when you don't want to display text `if ($products >= 18)`

Comment: if You echo in if else then both message will be display !!

Answer (score 0):

```
If ($products ['quantity'] < 18)
echo "18"
else
echo ""
```

By products listing:-

foreach ($products as $K => $v){
 If ($v ['quantity'] < 18){

}
}

Comment: Please include some more context/explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($products < 18) {
    echo "Some text";
}
else {
    echo "Some other text";
} 
?>
```